# Does HERE Map tile REST API support CORS

Tags: here-api

I'm going to use satellite tiles as texture for terrain mesh.
However when I create texture out of it I get security error.

Does HERE Map tiles server support CORS?
Or do I have to workaround it (proxy / php)?

Answer (score 0):

In General the tiles do support CORS , you should be able to check the response header for 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*' to verify that.

Comment: In Chrome it's OK (with Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*) however in FF 38 I get: "Error: WebGL: It is forbidden to load a WebGL texture from a cross-domain element that has not been validated with CORS. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/WebGL/Cross-Domain_Textures"
the response headers for firefox contains lowercased "access-control-allow-origin: *" - maybe that's the problem?

Not sure if it's important but I check that localy only so far (w/o web server)

Comment: Really strange , i still cant see an error in firefox, created a simple example by copying from developer.here.com , do you see a similar error on the following link as well ? http://jsfiddle.net/jithu1987/zhffLtpg/

Comment: I can see warning in firefox for CORS, but this is a bug in forefox bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1094911 and the map should still be shown using the latest JS API Release.

Comment: I put my simplified WebGL texture creation example here: http://jsfiddle.net/yn3q0pr8/2/ (which works in Chrome but not in FF)  
The error message is different - not sure if it's the same issue

Answer (score 0):

They used to. Something's changed recently and maps stopped working for externals. 
"No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource" is exactly the error you get now.
I'm trying to find information, perhaps a simple config mistake from HERE, but has been several days now though..

Edited:
Here's the HERE quick start map example (modified only for https mode) https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4728771/hack/here.html
It gives the error above and generates 403s.

Comment: Now updated my post with an example link. ping @Jithin

Comment: Strange, I don't see any error in chrome or firefox for the above link, can you try the following link, maybe there is some regional issue (just a wild guess ) http://jsfiddle.net/jithu1987/zhffLtpg/ @Fredik Blomqvist

Comment: Your fiddle works for me too. But HERE does aggressive caching, try to zoom to a different region of the world where it has to fetch new tiles? If you stay in Berlin you probably get your old cache. Then my example shows the "No cross origin header" again (I tried both both maps with both mine and your key). Interestingly when I try your key I get a single non-interactive Berlin view. Perhaps the key simply gone bad. But as said I have a client with same issue, and the starting poster in this thread it seems.

Comment: Regarding using the Keys, the keys in my example are demo ones, restricted to cit environment,and might not work in your example which uses the production environment. I also see a non-intractive map on your dropbox link because you have not initliazed the behaviour and ui components.I can see warning in firefox for CORS, but this is a bug in forefox https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1094911 and the map should still be shown using the latest JS API Release.

Comment: ah, yes, I copy-pasted the HERE quick start map as minimal example that apparently didn't add controls, my real map does that :) But still, I got simply a blank access-control-error response. Might be denied keys or regional stuff then (no heads up from HERE though). And, as said, I'm posting since also confirmed this for a client (with own keys). I'll do more tests, thanks for helping!